# Prefixed node path aliases with arguments in menu

Tags: routes, path-aliases

I already have code that will take a path such as www.example.com/site/123/campaign/456/mynodealias. It loads the aliased node with extra arguments, site and campaign, which could change at any time and could be potentially thousands of them.

I now need to display a menu that links to paths like the above. For example, let's say I start on the path www.example.com/site/123/campaign/456, and I have two nodes (mynodealias1, and mynodealias2). I would need a menu with links to my custom paths:

- www.example.com/site/123/campaign/456/mynodealias1
- www.example.com/site/123/campaign/456/mynodealias2

Do you have any suggestion about the best way to go about this?

Comment: Let's see if I understood. You have code that handles pages with a URL like www.example.com/site/123/campaign/456/mynodealias1, and you want to know how the page at www.example.com/site/123/campaign/456 could generate the links to the pages at `www.example.com/site/123/campaign/456/<node alias>`. If that is the case, are there restrictions about which node aliases should be used? For example, are the node aliases just for nodes of specific content types?

Comment: The alias could in fact be anything. Suppose I have a menu item: $items['myitem'] = array('title' => 'my item'); I would like to access this at: www.example.com/site/123/campaign/456/myitem, plus a menu to be available to the user that has the site and campaign urls. Or maybe I should have a menu item $items['site/%/campaign/%/myitem'] = array('title' => 'my item'); The main issue is generating displaying the menu with the extra arguments populated in the url.

Comment: I think the answer lies with the Persistent URL module (PURL). I've been having a look at Open Atrium and the Organic Groups functionality which is similar to what I need. i.e. Similar urls for pages but prefixed with the group identifier.